# Parabolic linear PDE with non-homogenous Neumann boundary condition.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set with lipschitz boundary,  $T>0$, $f \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$, $g \in L^2(0,T;H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega))$ and $h \in H^1(\Omega).$

I'm trying to prove the existence of weak solutions to the following parabolic problem
$$\begin{cases}
u'-\Delta u=f \; \;\ in \;\ \Omega \times]0,T[,\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}:= \nabla u \cdot \overrightarrow{n}=g\;\; on\;\partial \Omega \times]0,T[,\;\;\ \textbf{(boundary condition)}\\
u=h\;\;\; on\; \{0\}\times\Omega \;\;\ \textbf{(initial condition)}
\end{cases}
$$
I proceeded by using the Faedo-Galerkin method.
Consider:
$$V:=\{u\;\; |\;\ u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))\;\text{and}\; u' \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))\}$$ 
The weak formulation I obtained is the following (note that the test function is considered on space only).
$$\begin{cases}
\text{Finding } u \in V\; \text{satisftying}\; \forall v\in H^1(\Omega):\\
\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} u' v \;dx + \displaystyle \int_{\Omega} \nabla u . \nabla v \;dx=\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} f v \;dx + \displaystyle \int_{\partial \Omega} g v \;d\tau.
\end{cases}
$$
Let $$V_n:=Vect\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$$
where $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ is the eigenbasis generated by the following eigenvalue problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
- \Delta u= \alpha u\;\ in \; \Omega, \\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0\;\;\; on \;\partial \Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
This basis is orthonormal in $L^2(\Omega)$ and orthogonal in $H^1(\Omega).$
I have established the following:

$\bullet$ The existence of the solution to the finite dimensionnal problem (i.e in the space $V_n$), which is of the form
$$
u_n(x,t)=\sum_{i=1}^n d_k(t) e_k(x).
$$
$\bullet$ The boundedness of $u_n$ in the space $L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)).$ 

I still have to prove the boundedness of $u'_n$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega):$
Here is my attempt:

Since $u_n$ is a solution to the finite-dimensional problem, we have the following:
$$
\forall e_l \in V_n:
\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} u_n' e_l \;dx + \displaystyle \int_{\Omega} \nabla u_n . \nabla e_l \;dx=\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} f e_l \;dx + \displaystyle \int_{\partial \Omega} g e_l \;d\tau.
$$
Multiplying by $d_l'(t)$ and summing over $l$, we obtain:
$$
\Vert u_n'(t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \Vert \nabla u_n \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)^n}^2=\int_{\Omega} f u'_n \; dx+ \int_{\partial \Omega} u_n' g \;d\tau.
$$ 
By applying the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality and by continuity of the trace with $C>0$, we get 
$$
\Vert u_n'(t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \Vert \nabla u_n(t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)^n}^2 \leq \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)} \Vert u'_n(t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)} + C \Vert u_n'(t) \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)} \Vert g \Vert_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}
$$
Which yields,
$$
\Vert u_n'(t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \Vert \nabla u_n(t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)^n}^2 \leq \dfrac{1}{2} \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} \Vert u'_n(t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + C \Vert u_n'(t) \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)} \Vert g \Vert_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}
$$
I stopped here, the term $\Vert u_n'(t) \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)}$ is causing me problems, in the homogenous Neumann boundary condtitions' case it doesn't show and we can conclude by Gronwall lemma. Is there a way arround it in the non-homogenous case?

Comment: At the end you have to integrate wrt $t$ over $(0,s)$. What if you integrate $\int_{\partial \Omega} u_n'g$ directly? If $g$ is contant in time, then this integral can be estimated against $\| u_n(s)\|_{H^1}$, which could be compensated with second term on the lhs of you last equationa.

Comment: So instead of your approach: estimate, then integrate; reverse this for the boundary term: first integrate then estimate.

Comment: I proceeded the way you suggested and I found at the end the following

$$ \dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^{s} \Vert u'_n(t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+\dfrac{1}{2} \Vert \nabla u_n(s) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)^n}^2 \leq \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^s \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)} + C \left( \Vert u_n(s) \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)} - ( \Vert u_n(0) \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)}\right) \Vert g \Vert_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}+\dfrac{1}{2} \Vert\nabla u_n(0)\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)^n}^2$$

Comment: By doing so, I've lost the term $\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \Vert \nabla u_n \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)^n}^2,$ the estimation I'm hoping to get is an energy estimate, since I already have an estimate of the form  $\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \Vert u_n \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \leq ....... ,$ so I would like to find an estimate of the form   $\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dt} \Vert \nabla u_n \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)^n}^2\leq ............$

Comment: What if you add both of these estimates? Then on the lhs you get $\frac d{dt}\|u_n\|_{H^1}^2$, integrating this should be able to compensate for the boundary term.